# How to stop VTK Timer

Tags: vtk

I am doing an animation program with VTK python, I don't understand how to stop or pause
this animation. Somebody please tell me on how to stop this timer. Right now my animation
is continuing for infinite time, I tried to put my code in for loop but it failed to stop.
please note my below code and someone kindly share some idea.

**Code lines:**

```
renderWindowInteractor.AddObserver('TimerEvent', cb.execute)
timerId = renderWindowInteractor.CreateRepeatingTimer(10);
```

**Detailed Code lines:**

```
class vtkTimerCallback():

def __init__(self):

   self.timer_count = 0
   self.timerCycle=0 

def execute(self,obj,event):

   self.timerCycle+=1
   if self.timerCycle==3:       
      self.timerCycle=0      
      for A in range(3):
          for B in range(2):
              for C in range(1):
                  self.actor.SetPosition(A,1,C);
                  iren = obj
                  iren.GetRenderWindow().Render()
                  self.timer_count += 1      
   else:           

      for X in range(1):
          for Y in range(2):
              for Z in range(3):
                  self.actor.SetPosition(1,Y,Z);
                  iren = obj
                  iren.GetRenderWindow().Render()
                  self.timer_count += 1  



class Cone():


def animation(self,obj_renwin):

    renderwininstance=obj_renwin             
    renderWindowInteractor = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
    renderWindowInteractor.SetRenderWindow(obj_renwin.renwin)
    obj_renwin.renwin.Render()
    renderWindowInteractor.Initialize()                   

    cb = vtkTimerCallback()
    cb.actor = obj_renwin.actor
    for X in range(2):
        print "animation time is" + str(X)
        renderWindowInteractor.AddObserver('TimerEvent', cb.execute)       
        timerId = renderWindowInteractor.CreateRepeatingTimer(10);


cone_Obj = Cone()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you use the timer into vtkRenderWindowInteractor object, there you start the timer:

```
renderWindowInteractor->CreateRepeatingTimer(100);
```

so, vtkRenderWindowInteractor can pause, and stop the timer:

here, you see some details:
http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkRenderWindowInteractor.html#a7ef06e3e7c8cff5767c3b0d328934f55

Comment: @flaiv, This works, but the issue is if I again want to start the timer animation function the program crashes when I click animate button, getting a error message like this "Python exe has stopped working". The error is hitting following line self.renderWindowInteractor.SetRenderWindow(obj_renwin.renwin). Do you have any idea, or any sample animation program with play and pause. If you have, could you please share?

Comment: Unfortunately, I never worked by timers in VTK. I have seen that it is no "StopTimer" method, which tell me that the timer could be stopped by other method, or by an artificial way, such as ResetTimer, or something ... VTK is an good library, but there is so less people that could give some answers to so much questions ... :( I am the one hwo work in VTK for few weeks ... I would like to help you a lot, but I can not ... other source could be wiki examples, but they are so limited, that almoust can not be used in real applications ...

Comment: @flaiv, no problem, appreciate you for helping me

Comment: It comes an ideea, which I gave you here: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25595161/how-to-pause-and-restart-an-animation-in-vtk[/link]