# How to pause and restart an animation in VTK

Tags: python, vtk

I am trying to do an animation program in VTK, in which I could make the VTK objects animate
but I failed to do pausing animation and restart animation, I came to know recently to stop the VTK timer but after if I click the animate button again to start then the program got crashed with following error, I have only one clue that the following line is crashing but this line will work at the first time of animation button click but fails on the second button click!!. The second function "animation_Stop" is my attempt of stopping the function by destroying the whole function, so I hoped I could avoid the program crash but it was also a failure!!

**Error:**

*python.exe has stopped working*

Error line:

```
self.renderWindowInteractor.SetRenderWindow(obj_renwin.renwin)
```

Please note my detailed code lines for animation and someone please help me to restart
and pause the animation in vtk python

```
def animation(self,obj_renwin,X):

    if X==1: 

           print "start or restart animation"

           self.renderWindowInteractor = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()      
           objRen=self.renderWindowInteractor.GetRenderWindow()                   
           self.renderWindowInteractor.SetRenderWindow(obj_renwin.renwin)                         
           obj_renwin.renwin.Render()
           self.renderWindowInteractor.Initialize()
           cb = vtkTimerCallback()
           cb.actor = obj_renwin.actor
           self.renderWindowInteractor.AddObserver('TimerEvent', cb.execute)
           self.timerId = self.renderWindowInteractor.CreateRepeatingTimer(5);


    if X==2:

        print "stop animation"                       
        self.renderWindowInteractor.DestroyTimer(self.timerId)



def animation_Stop(self,obj_renwin):

    print "stop animation"        
    #self.animation(obj_renwin,1).destroy()
    del (ConeRender.Cone.animation)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you start the vtkTimer like that:

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkTimerCallback> cb = 
vtkSmartPointer<vtkTimerCallback>::New();
interactor->AddObserver(vtkCommand::TimerEvent, cb);
```

you may consider to stop/pause the timer with

```
vtkCommand::EndInteraction
```

i.e.

```
interactor->InvokeEvent(vtkCommand::TimerEvent, cb);
```

[It is just a moment thought, you can try it] ... :)